# StackOverflowError from Custom Moshi Adapter

Tags: java, android, retrofit, stack-overflow, moshi

I created a moshi adapter to address null String values:

```
public class NullStringAdapter {
    @FromJson
    public String stringFromJson(@Nullable String value) {
        if (value.equals(null)) {
            return "nulled";
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

I created a Moshi instance with it and added it to my retrofit:

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(new NullStringAdapter()).build();
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseURL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .client(client)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

}

At runtime, I get a StackOverflowError from a repetitive method in the MoshiAdapterMethodsFactory:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
                  at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.cacheKey(Moshi.java:140)
                  at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:69)
 at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$5.fromJson(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:212)
 at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$1.fromJson(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:81)     
 at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$5.fromJson(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:212)
 at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$1.fromJson(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:81)     
 at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$5.fromJson(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:212)
 at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$1.fromJson(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:81)
```

.... and so on.

The two problem code areas are line 212:

```
@Override public Object fromJson(Moshi moshi, JsonReader reader)
        throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
      JsonAdapter<Object> delegate = moshi.adapter(parameterTypes[0], qualifierAnnotations);
      *****Object intermediate = delegate.fromJson(reader);*****
      return method.invoke(adapter, intermediate);
    }
```

And line 81:

```
@Override public Object fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (fromAdapter == null) {
      return delegate.fromJson(reader);
    } else if (!fromAdapter.nullable && reader.peek() == JsonReader.Token.NULL) {
      reader.nextNull();
      return null;
    } else {
      try {
        *****return fromAdapter.fromJson(moshi, reader);*****
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new AssertionError();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof IOException) throw (IOException) e.getCause();
        throw new JsonDataException(e.getCause() + " at " + reader.getPath());
      }
    }
  }
```

Why is the method factory endlessly generating these methods?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to adapt `String` to `String`, that's what creates the loop thus resulting in a `StackOverflowError`. Create a custom annotation for all the strings that you expect to have the `"nulled"` value, smth like this:

```
@JsonQualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NullableString { }
```

And then change your adapter to:

```
public class NullStringAdapter {
  @FromJson @NullableString
  public String stringFromJson(@Nullable String value) {
    if (value.equals(null)) {
        return "nulled";
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Or if you want to enforce this type or deserializing to every `String` in you parse from json (**altho I would not advice for that**) you can declare your adapter using a factory:

```
public static final JsonAdapter.Factory FACTORY = new JsonAdapter.Factory() {
  @Override public JsonAdapter<?> create(Type type, Set<? extends Annotation> annotations, Moshi moshi) {
    if (!annotations.isEmpty()) return null;

    Class<?> rawType = Types.getRawType(type);
    if (rawType.equals(String.class) return /** your custom JsonAdapter here. */;

    return null;
  }
};
```